# Iterate over loop and adding list to dataframe in new row or new column

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe

I'm sure this is simple but I'm quite new to Python. I have trouble how to add a list to a dataframe column or row after each iteration of the loop.
I want to loop through a list of around hundred URLs with the outer for-loop and extract the data with the inner loop. Every time

With the code now I can create a dataframe that appends all lists together to one column or one row in the dataframe. But I want every iteration of the inner loop seperately in a new colum or row of the dataframe.

```
list_rows = [] 
for x in link_href_list: 
    urllib.request.urlopen(x)
    html = urlopen(x)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")    
    table=bs.find('tbody')
    rows = table.tr.next_siblings

    for row in rows:
        a=row.find('td').get_text().strip()
        list_rows.append(a)
list_rows.to_frame()
```

Unfortunately the lists of the inner loop will have different lengths!
maybe someone has a simple solution or a hint what I could change? Thanks!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I want the output of each iteration of the inner loop in a new column or row in a dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant every iteration of the outer loop in a new "row".
This would create a 2 dimensional array (list) as a result, for each element in link_href_list you would get a new "row". Although, I have no idea what the to_frame() method is, I assume it is a printout.

```
list_columns = [] 
for x in link_href_list: 
    urllib.request.urlopen(x)
    html = urlopen(x)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")    
    table=bs.find('tbody')
    rows = table.tr.next_siblings
    list_rows = []

    for row in rows:
        a=row.find('td').get_text().strip()
        list_rows.append(a)
    list_columns.append(list_rows)
list_columns.DataFrame()
```

Edit: If the to_frame is the pandas DataFrame thing, i am not entirely sure how will it handle different lengths. I will check in a couple, but there is a way around that as well. 
It seems that a very simle answer on how to import different length lists is not at hand and finding the longest list and adjust the pandas import accordingly and make the lists of equal length in a new loop.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well. Now I get a two dimensional dataframe. You were right, I had to change the to_frame in ´pd.DataFrame()´

Comment: Cool to hear it helped. This actually got me to resurrect my older project of automatic music composition. :-) I'll just modify the source to reflect what worked. Could you just update the question with what are the inputs and what the responses are, so the data in the question would be complete? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be just creating an empty list outside, then appending inside the loop, you you have tried. You're issue seems to be creating the Dataframe. I would have just commented under the answer above for the reference of others, however I cannot leave comments at this rep.

Define your columns and then create the dataframe using [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
 import pandas as pd
 cols = ['col_1','col_2',...,'col_n']
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_cols, columns=cols)
```

The answer above creates a list (`list_columns = []`) which then tries to convert to a Dataframe. This should throw the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<ipython-input-396-dc539f26ae12>", line 1, in <module>
    list_columns.Dataframe()

 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```